# SQL 2008 replication/mirroring in both directions

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is it possible to have mirroring/replication in both directions? From DB1 to DB2 and from DB2 to DB1 that i can write and read in both DB and they will be synchronized all the time.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The mirror is unreadable and cannot be updated to start with, so there is no question of synchronizing the mirror changes since there cannot be any changes in the mirror.

Answer (score 1):

Merge replication and transactional replication allow updating data at subscribers and propagating changes back to publisher. By default, transactional replication subscribers do not propagate changes back, though.

See: "Updating data at Subscribers" in [Selecting the Appropriate Type of Replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152565.aspx)